About evolution problem with variable coefficients.
I'm studying differential operators. For example, in the evolution equation
\begin{align}
u_t&=(1-\partial_x^2)u\\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{align}
Question 1. Does this problem have any name in the literature?
the symbol of the operator $(1-\partial_x^2)$ is $(1+\xi^2)$. Now, the operator $(1+x^2)(1-\partial_x^2)$ has the symbol $(1+x^2)(1+\xi^2)$.
Question 2. Is there some problem as
\begin{align}
u_t&=(1+x^2)(1-\partial_x^2)u\\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{align}
or this has non sense?
Thanks

1a. It is a backwards heat equation with source term, which is ill-posed, and so of limited use. 1b. I don’t think it makes sense to have a Fourier(?) symbol of an operator that has variable coefficients.  2. It is a variable coefficient backward heat equation that is ill-posed and thus of limited use.
